# Markdown links within a bullet list are not resolving

Tags: html, css, markdown, jekyll

I'm trying to create a bulleted list of links using Markdown and Jekyll for my blog and getting some strange behavior.

```
Finally, many of the data sets that were used in the studies mentioned above are open source and freely available.  
-   [Visceral](http://www.visceral.eu/)
-   [ImageNet](http://image-net.org/)
-   [Kaggle Data Science Bowl](https://www.kaggle.com/c/data-science-bowl-2017)
-   [Grand Challenge](https://grand-challenge.org/All_Challenges/)
-   [Lung Image Database Consortium](https://imaging.cancer.gov/programsandresources/informationsystems/lidc)
-   [Multimodal Brain Tumor Segmentation Challenge](http://braintumorsegmentation.org/)

 Thanks for reading, and please feel free to [reach out](http://healthcare.ai/contact) with questions!
```

The output looks like this on my site:

[image]

The links within the bulleted list work correctly, but they are not underlined. The links within the paragraph are underlined. I would like all links to appear underlined.

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue. Where's your CSS?

Comment: as mentioned by @Michael it seems that it's just about your CSS, and not jekyll. so, check your css files and update the `li` css style. if you need more help.just update the question with more info :)

Comment: Thanks for the help all. It definitely is in our CSS. However, we are going to ignore the issue for now due to an impending website rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this (very ugly) code to your body/layout:

```
<style>
li a {text-decoration: underline!important;}
</style>
```

Or, even better, add only the CSS to your stylesheet.

If you have gotten this far, you probably also want to make it more specific, by adding a ancestor/parent class in front of the 'li a' selector.